# replace if file exist when unzipping multiple zip files using vbs

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd, unzip

I have a VBScript which recursively executes and unzips multiple zip files in a folder into another directory. I would like to add another have an option to replace existing files incase of duplicates.

Below is the VBS

```
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments

ZipFile = objArgs(0)

ExtractTo = objArgs(1)

'If the extraction location does not exist create it.
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If NOT fso.FolderExists(ExtractTo) Then
   fso.CreateFolder(ExtractTo)
End If

'Extract the contants of the zip file.
set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).items
objShell.NameSpace(ExtractTo).CopyHere(FilesInZip)
Set fso = Nothing
Dim objShell
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")


' Using Set is mandatory
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Below is my batch script which calls this vbs recursively.

```
for %%A in ("%2\*.zip") do "%1" "%%A" "%3"
```

Comment: You should use proper quotation: `for %%A in ("%~2\*.zip") do "%~1" "%%~A" "%~3"` (the `~` avoids double-quotation)...

Comment: The `CopyHere` method accepts an options argument, I guess there is one that suits your needs...

Comment: How do I use arguments for CopyHere in VBScript. The Question was marked as duplicate, how ever the other one is about powershell and it did not work when I use it in vbs.

Comment: I meant like `.CopyHere(FilesInZip, 16)`...

Comment: It says "Cannot use parentheses when calling a sub"

Comment: Hm...  let me think... then I would suggest to try without the parentheses...

Comment: Great! that works. Thanks a lot! @aschipfl